# What word do we use to mean "evening breakfast"?

Tags: word-usage

Usually we use the word "breakfast" in the morning to mean to eat something, but what word do we use to mean "afternoon breakfast" and "evening breakfast"?

Comment: The expression "wedding breakfast" is the first meal eaten by the bride and groom and their guests after their marriage. This can be at any time of the day. Nowadays people usually speak of the "wedding reception" instead, but "wedding breakfast" is still sometimes used.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you think "breakfast" means "meal," but breakfast really means "meal eaten in the morning." For a meal eaten in the afternoon, the term is "lunch." For a meal eaten when the sun is going down or later, the term is "dinner" or "supper." Food eaten between meals is usually called a "snack."

NOTE: This answer only applies to the part of the United States where I live. Apparently, different English speakers around the world have different terminology.

Comment: However, many restaurants now offer "all day breakfast", meaning that they will serve the kind of dishes that are customary at breakfast at any time of day. But we would normally call the meal "breakfast" if we had it at another time in the day: we might say "I'm having the all-day breakfast for my lunch".

Comment: I note this from Wikipedia, having often been called to a large Sunday midday meal as a youth with the words: **Dinner is on the table.**                                                                    "Does dinner mean lunch?
Image result for dinner
While the 1945 edition of Emily Post's Etiquette described dinner as a meal eaten either at midday or in the evening, by the 1960s, the guide refers to the midday meal as lunch."

Comment: "Dinner" usually means the last meal of the day, but it can also mean simply the largest meal of the day. For example, Thanksgiving dinner (or this Sunday meal you mention) is often eaten mid-afternoon or even earlier. But generally, you would not say _dinner is on the table_ during lunch hours (11 a.m. to 3 p.m.). Instead, you might just say _lunch is on the table_ or _food is ready_.

Comment: @Ringo - "Dinner" usually means the last meal of the day" - not where I come from.

Comment: In the UK there is a big North/South divide on meal naming. Taking the 'standard three meals a day' the South has breakfast, lunch, dinner, the North has breakfast, dinner, tea. I'd never heard of lunch until after I left school & started work in a national company. [& I now see a lot of this is covered in comments under another answer;)

Comment: @gonefishin'again. I think the big takeaway is that all these terms are so common that they're often used informally and interchangeably.

Comment: @Ringo - No. My entire point is that to a native of one area compared to another they are *not* interchangeable. Dinner means two different meals at different ends of a small country. I've now lived in the South for 30 years & I *still* get confused by what to me is the 'wrong' usage.

Comment: Ah OK, I get it now. I think where I'm from people throw around terms less formally.

Comment: @Ringo - it's not a case of formality. The words literally mean different things. It's like calling a dog a cat. It's simply "the wrong word". It is something that through modern communication & greater travel we manage to cope with the difference just fine, but the 'home' version always feels more 'correct' to each native of opposite ends of the country.

Answer (score 1):

"Breakfast" means a meal eaten shortly after you wake up.

For most people this means a meal that you eat in the morning.  For most people a meal that you eat in the afternoon is "lunch" and a meal in the evening is "supper" (or "dinner" or "tea" - depending on dialect)

If you work at night and wake up in the afternoon you might say.

> Joe works the night shift and so he wakes up at 5pm.  He has his breakfast in the evening, and his supper at 7am.

But this is unusual.  You have to explain why Joe wakes up in the evening.

"Breakfast" can also mean "a meal like that commonly served at breakfast" (in the UK that might mean cereal, toast, bacon, eggs). Some restaurants serve "all-day-breakfast". You might say "I'm having the all-day-breakfast for my tea."

Comment: Beat your answer by 12 seconds, but your answer is at least 12 seconds better than mine. :-)

Comment: When we eat breakfast, we **break** the **fast** imposed by the fact that we sleep during the night. My East Midlands (England) grandmother pronounced the 'break' part like the verb meaning to 'to separate into parts with suddenness or violence'.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for **tea** (also known by some as *afternoon tea* and once known by some as *tiffin*) which is served in the middle of the afternoon.

*High tea*, which might include hot food, is served a little later and sometimes replaces dinner (which some call 'tea' and some call 'supper').

**Supper** is the last meal of the day and is eaten late in the evening.

Comment: Since taking up with my partner from Lancashire, I have been obliged to call the three meals of the day breakfast, dinner, and tea. In fact, these were the names of my London childhood, but when I grew up there was a spell when I used the Southern variants breakfast, lunch, dinner. In either case, supper is a kind of snack taken late at night before bed.

Comment: I grew up in Boston (East Coast of the U.S.), where the terms are _breakfast_, _lunch_, and _supper_. I now live in San Diego (West Coast), where the terms are _breakfast_, _lunch_, and _dinner_. If you use the term _dinner_ in Boston, nobody would take notice, but if you use the term _supper_ in California, people might think that's weird. On both coasts, nobody says _supper_ meaning a late snack, and nobody ever says _tea_ unless they're literally drinking a cup of tea.

Comment: @Ringo - "How the Enchanting and Elusive Supper Club Came to California" - [California.com](https://www.california.com/enchanting-and-elusive-supper-club-california/)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Ha, yes, I've been to the San Francisco Supper Club in the Mission District a few times, but I want to say it's not there anymore. My feeling is that so few people are actually attending "supper clubs" in the urban areas of California today that they might exist, but it's not really a part of the vernacular of your common Californian. These very exclusive clubs are both invite-only and extremely expensive, and you might do outrageous things like eat off a waterbed in your underwear late at night, while performers do cabaret nearby. I think it might be a fad that proves the point

Comment: @Michael Harvey: I couldn't get a handle on these words. In Kent we had school dinners at lunch time or packed lunches at dinner time! My Geordie parents were forever trying to adapt. The third meal of the day had been 'tea', but they started calling it 'supper', and we only had 'tea' on Sundays, when it meant an uncooked meal featuring bread and dripping. BTW, doesn't the boy's father in The Singing Detective - set in the Forest of Dean - irritate his snobbish wife by calling it 'tea'? I think it became a class thing, like napkin/serviette.

Comment: @Ringo: That was all very interesting. I didn't know about the East/West divergence. I recommend _afternoon tea_! Tiny crustless sandwiches, toasted teacakes (the English type), scones with jam and clotted cream... Yum!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - at school we had dinner time, when we went to the dinner room and were served by dinner ladies, except, as you say if Mum made a packed lunch like on Sports Day (spam sandwiches v. often). Bread and dripping! Lovely. We had serviettes and a toilet but Grandma on Dad's (posh) side had napkins and a lavatory.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I've had "tea" a few times and enjoyed it immensely. There was a Victorian-style tea room in San Francisco that would serve "high tea" -- I remember things like cucumber sandwiches and clotted cream. And everyone is wearing their Sunday best. I also remember as a child reading a cartoon called "Oor Wullie" where he was always trying to get his hands on scones and "treacle," which I take to be a kind of "dripping" you mention above. I've never heard of a dripping before -- at least not in a food context.